# Yii2: Implement bootstrap 4 checkboxes style in yii\grid\CheckboxColumn

Tags: checkbox, yii2, grid, widget, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and YII 2 and I want to customize my checkbox inputs like the next link

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes.

So I'm using the **`yii\grid\CheckboxColumn`** class, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried the following

```
'columns' => [
   [
     'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
     'cssClass' => 'checkbox-select',
     'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:5px'],
     'header' =>  '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">'.Html::checkBox('selection_all', false, ['id' => 'customCheck1', 'type' => 'checkbox', 'class' => 'custom-control-input select-on-check-all']).'<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"></label></div>',
     'checkboxOptions' => function($model){
        return ['<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">'.Html::checkBox('selection', false, ['id' => "'customCheck".$model->id."'", 'class' => 'custom-control-input']).'<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck'.$model->id.'"></label></div>'];
     },
   ],
],
```

It only works in the table header but not in the other checkboxes.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Looks like it is fixed now and merged in the `yii3.0.0-alpha1` release see [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/f5665a054466bafeaae3346e87792dee5a18ece4)

---

You are using the [**`checkboxOptions`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html#$checkboxOptions-detail) wrong way according to DOCS

> The HTML attributes for checkboxes. This can either be an **`array`** of
>   attributes or an anonymous function (Closure) that returns such an
>   **`array`**.

Means, either way, it should be an array of `attributes`, moreover, you should use the following `options` to assign the `classes` and `attributes` for the checkboxes in `body` and `header`, you dont need the label for the checkboxes.

```
[ 'class' => \yii\grid\CheckboxColumn::className () ,
    'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return [
            'value' => $model->id ,
            'class' => 'custom-control-input' ,
            'id' => 'customCheck' . $model->id
        ];
    } ,
    'contentOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return [
            'class' => 'custom-control custom-checkbox' ,
        ];
    } ,
    'header' => '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">' . Html::checkBox ( 'selection_all' , false , [ 'id' => 'customCheck1' , 'type' => 'checkbox' , 'class' => 'custom-control-input select-on-check-all' ] ) . '<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"></label></div>' ,
] ,
```

**EDIT**

There is an [**`ISSUE`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/issues/168) related to the bootstrap awesome checkboxes and `gridview` not being compatible and this issue is still not merged, as you said you want the `label` tag and the `div` wrapper inside the `td` of each cell rendering the checkbox and for this you need to just use the `content` option to customize the feel and look of the checkboxes in the body of `GridView`.

But for the above to work currently what you have to do is just copy paste the following extended class that includes the fix for the gridview and save with the name **`CheckboxColumnCustom.php`** in the folder
**`common/components/`**

```
<?php

namespace common\components;
use Closure;

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\grid\CheckboxColumn;

class CheckboxColumnCustom extends CheckboxColumn
{

    public $content;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index)
    {
        if ($this->content instanceof Closure) {
            $checkbox = call_user_func($this->content, $model, $key, $index, $this);
        } else {
            $checkbox = $this->getContentCheckBox($model,$key,$index);
        }
        return $checkbox;
    }

    public function getContentCheckBox($model,$key,$index)
    {
        if ($this->checkboxOptions instanceof Closure) {
            $options = call_user_func($this->checkboxOptions, $model, $key, $index, $this);
        } else {
            $options = $this->checkboxOptions;
        }
        if (!isset($options['value'])) {
            $options['value'] = is_array($key) ? Json::encode($key) : $key;
        }
        if ($this->cssClass !== null) {
            Html::addCssClass($options, $this->cssClass);
        }
        return Html::checkbox($this->name, !empty($options['checked']), $options);
    }

}
```

and then update your code for the checkboxColumn to the following

```
[ 
    'class' => \common\components\CheckboxColumnCustom::className () ,
    'content' => function($model) {
        return  '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">' . Html::checkBox ( 'selection' , false , [ 'id' => "'customCheck" . $model->id . "'" , 'class' => 'custom-control-input' ] ) . '<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck' . $model->id . '"></label></div>';
    } ,
    'header' => '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">' . Html::checkBox ( 'selection_all' , false , [ 'id' => 'customCheck1' , 'type' => 'checkbox' , 'class' => 'custom-control-input select-on-check-all' ] ) . '<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"></label></div>' ,
] ,
```

I just tested the code and it works perfectly and generates the exact string that is returned from the `content` option.

Comment: whoever tried to serialize downvote me it wont help you dude.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But actually I need the label tag, because if I skip it the bootstrap class is not aplied, and my checkbox disappear

Comment: @OmarSanchez i just updated the answer there is a known issue for working with bootstrap check boxes i have added a fix for you that will work.

Comment: I had almost the same idea, only that I use the renderDataCellContent function to wrap with the div the checkbox and the label and in the column I use checkboxOptions. I tried what you post and also works Thanks Muhammad